# How to test WCF services with ADFS using WCFTestClient

Tags: wcf, testing

I have ADFS WCF service and I am not able to test it using WCFTestClient executable.
Is it possible to test it with the WCFTestClient?

If not, what is the best way to test the service?

Comment: What is ADFS?   WCF Test Client is pretty good, but somethings it can't test.  In that case you can use other tools, like SoapUI.

Comment: ADFS is a federated security approach used for  secured WCF services. here is link about WCF with ADFS https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2011/08/17/federated-security-how-to-setup-and-call-a-wcf-service-secured-by-adfs-2-0/. I am not able to use WCFTestClient to test the WCF service with ADFS token.

Comment: Take a look at SoapUI - I don't think WCF Test Client can handle these kind of scenarios.